# OkHttp debugging Network Log tracing -> requestBodyStart, requestBodyEnd, responseBodyStart, responseBodyEnd

Tags: java, network-programming, retrofit2, okhttp

I am debugging network traces of my application which uses okhttp client to make http call. Enabled EventListener for detailed debugging and observed below details

```
[2023-05-05 18:20:27.899] - requestBodyStart
[2023-05-05 18:20:28.240] - requestBodyEnd
[2023-05-05 18:20:28.417] - responseBodyStart
[2023-05-05 18:20:28.417] - responseBodyEnd
```

OkHttp documentation does not provide enough information on these events.

1. What does the time difference between requestBodyStart and requestBodyEnd denote ?
2. What time difference between requestBodyEnd and responseBodyStart denote ?
3. Is there a network call involved between requestBodyStart and requestBodyEnd or its just the client config and request payload.

Answer (score 0):

1. This denotes time to write the entire request to your network stack’s outbound buffer. If the request body is larger than this buffer, this will include time waiting for the peer to acknowledge received data.
2. This is the time it takes the server to receive the request and transmit the beginning of the response.
3. This depends on whether your request fits in the outbound buffer. OkHttp doesn’t differentiate between data being enqueued and data being transmitted.